# How do I change VSCode's default explorer side bar order?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, text-editor

When I open a new vscode project, I always need to manually change the order of the accordions in the explorer tab. Personally, I always like to have a source control accordion but it takes over half the side bar above the file explorer accordion. How can I explicitly set the default order of accordions and save time setting up my editor?

### Example:

[image: Vscode explorer accordions]

<sub>`Visualivre` refers to the file explorer (the name of the project)</sub>

Comment: you can drag/drop the views to a new location

Comment: I know, i'm asking for a way to do it permanently

Comment: the workspace should remember the changed location

Comment: it doesnt remeber tho